# Prove: $\lim\limits_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^\frac12}=0$

Tags: limits

Prove:

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^\frac12}=0$$

Thanks for your help. Thanks ahead:)

Comment: 30 months on the site, 300+ questions asked, and you post... this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a more general note, it's often helpful to set $x = \rho \cos \theta$, $ y = \rho \sin \theta$.
So it becomes

$$\lim_{\rho \to 0} \frac{\rho^2 \cos \theta \sin \theta}{|\rho|} = \lim_{\rho \to 0} \rho  \cos \theta \sin \theta $$

Since $$|\rho  \cos \theta \sin \theta| \le \rho \to 0,$$the limit is $0$

Answer (score 4):

$$
\left|\frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right|=\left|x\right|\frac{\left|y\right|}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\leq\left|x\right|\to 0
$$
since $\left|y\right|\leq\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$

Answer (score 2):

$$\left|\frac{xy}{(x^2+y^2)^\frac{1}{2}}\right|\le \left|\frac{xy}{(xy)^\frac{1}{2}}\right|=\left|x^\frac{1}{2}y^\frac{1}{2}\right|\to 0\text{ as }(x,y)\to (0,0)$$